# how do i select all inputs by class?

Tags: jquery

I have a situation where some JS code changes my divs class :

```
<div class="form signed">
```

Becomes

```
<div class="signed form-sml">
```

I am trying to select all the input fields within this div :

```
$(".form, .form-sml :input)
```

This will select form-sml inputs but not form inputs. How do I select both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jQuery supports multiple selection](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) by using commas to separate your individual selectors, which will select elements that satisfy either of the selectors as seen below :

```
// This should select all <input> elements within either 'form' or 'form-sml' classes
$('.form :input,.form-sml :input')
```

Likewise, if you know that your class name is going to be begin with "form", you could use the [starts-with selector `^=`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to handle the same scenario :

```
// This will target any <input> elements within any classes that begin with "form"
$('[class^="form"] :input')
```

**Example**

You can [see a working example here](http://jsbin.com/tumeqa/edit?html,output) that can be seen below :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".form :input, .form-sml :input)
```

should do it...